# messages SlowQueries in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

we have problem with bad performance in own tomcat(7.0.42) liferay6.2 . We obtain these messages SlowQueries with native queries of liferay

```
> Jun 29, 2016 3:40:06 PM
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport               
> reportSlowQuery WARNING: Slow Query Report SQL=select
> userimpl0_.userId as userId363_, userimpl0_.uuid_ as uuid2_363_,
> userimpl0_.companyId as companyId363_, userimpl0_.createDate as
> createDate363_, userimpl0_.modifiedDate as modified5_363_,
> userimpl0_.defaultUser as defaultU6_363_, userimpl0_.contactId as
> contactId363_,userimpl0_.password_ as password8_363_,
> userimpl0_.passwordEncrypted as password9_363_, .....
> )AND(userimpl0_.screenName=? ); time=13315 ms;
```

I have checkes same querys direcly in BBDD and have good perfomance and good time 10ms.

My question is what size Tomcat 7? where i can found method for calculation tomcat time?

Comment: Which is the underlying DB being used?Try using some plugin to calculate time to execute slow queries for that.As for Tomcat,it's size should not be cause of an issue for the slow queries!

Comment: The DB is Oracle RAC and we can check using oracle tools don't exist queries slow.
Some Query show by tomcat we calculate explain plan and execution time direcly in DB and has faster response.